# Change caption number of an algorithm to format `chapter.number`

Tags: xetex

I'm using `Xelatex`.

```
\begin{algorithm}[htb]
 \caption{Algorithm}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
// algorithm
 \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
```

The caption is like `Algorithm 1`, `Algorithm 2`.

But there are many chapters in my paper, I'd like the caption with format of `chapter.number`, such as `1.1`, `1.2` in chapter one.

Comment: `biblatex` has nothing to do with this. Please post a complete minimal example. At the very least we need the document class and the package(s) you are using for the algorithms.

Comment: Try adding to your preamble `\counterwithin{algorithm}{within}`.

Comment: If you are using the `algorithm2e` package then use the package option `algochapter`.